# Le « harbinger of death » qualifiant l'animé ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, oral, comparaison-de-langues

> [...] Anyway, Mr. NBE-1 here, aka MEGATRON... [glares at Simmons]
>   That's what they call HIM... who's pretty much *the* **harbinger of
>   death**, wants to use the cube to transform human technology to take
>   over the universe. [...]
>
> [*Transformers*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0418279/quotes?item=qt0478264), 2007

C'est au moins en partie l'idée du [*quelque chose qui montre ce qui s'en vient*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/harbinger), du [signe avant-coureur](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/harbinger/585448). Mais le fait de parler d'un personnage en particulier, a fortiori avec un déterminant défini (*the*...), fait qu'un truc comme *le signe* semble faible ou d'un type inadéquat, à mon avis. En s'inspirant de l'[origine](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=harbinger) de l'emprunt du mot en anglais, ça donnerait l'*hébergeur* de la mort, plus que loufoque ! On note aussi au passage qu'on a indépendamment en anglais le [*grim reaper*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/grim%20reaper) tout comme le [*herald*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/herald), et on a un souci de cohérence. Il y a enfin la question de ce qui est le plus usuel à l'oral, avec les impératifs du dialogue.

---

Comment préfère-t-on rendre ou transposer ce *harbinger of death* dans un tel contexte, et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je dirais **le messager de la mort**. Il y a la notion de *précéder la mort* et *informer qu'elle arrive*, le terme *messager* s'applique bien pour un personnage (alors que *signe* ou *présage* sont plus abstraits). Et ça sonne vraiment cool.

Answer (score 2):

Without discussing its standing as fine literature, considering the ancient back-story and fantasy-ridden context of *The Transformers*, I think the French version of “Harbinger of Death”  as it’s to be used here could and should contain some literary and/or archaic flavor.
With this “criteria” in mind, regardless of whether one considers Megatron as a person or a thing, I think either [**précurseur**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9curseur) or (in spite of you having already mentioned [& dismissed?] its English version, *herald*) the figurative sense of [**héraut**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/h%C3%A9raut) could both be considered as distant “also rans” to Simon Déchamps’ good answer:

Précurseur
B. − Ce qui précède et annonce autre chose.
1. ….,

2. Être, chose ou événement présageant la venue d'une autre chose, d'un autre événement.

Héraut
B. − Au fig. Celui qui annonce la venue de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose **ou** qui en chante les louanges.
(both from *CNRTL* with emphasis added to the “ou” in the entry for “Héraut”)

Of these two, I would prefer
“**le héraut** de la mort,”
 both for its added archaic flavor and because [this n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+h%C3%A9raut%2Cle+pr%C3%A9curseur%2Cl%27h%C3%A9raut%2Cun+h%C3%A9raut%2Cun+pr%C3%A9curseur&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cle%20h%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ble%20h%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLe%20h%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20H%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLe%20H%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLE%20H%C3%89RAUT%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cle%20pr%C3%A9curseur%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ble%20pr%C3%A9curseur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20Pr%C3%A9curseur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLe%20Pr%C3%A9curseur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLe%20pr%C3%A9curseur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cl%27%20h%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bl%27%20H%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bl%27%20h%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cun%20h%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bun%20h%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUn%20h%C3%A9raut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cun%20pr%C3%A9curseur%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bun%20pr%C3%A9curseur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUn%20pr%C3%A9curseur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUN%20PR%C3%89CURSEUR%3B%2Cc0) seems to indicate that “**le** is used more than “un” with” héraut”  (whereas “un” is used more than “le” with “précurseur”).
(please note that you may have to re-click the blue search button to get the results)

(but see [this n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+h%C3%A9raut+de+la+mort%2Cle+pr%C3%A9curseur+de+la+mort%2Cun+messager+de+la+mort%2Cle+messager+de+la+mort%2Cun+h%C3%A9raut+de+la+mort%2Cun+pr%C3%A9curseur+de+la+mort&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20h%C3%A9raut%20de%20la%20mort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20pr%C3%A9curseur%20de%20la%20mort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20messager%20de%20la%20mort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20messager%20de%20la%20mort%3B%2Cc0) with “un/le messager” and “de la mort” added to the search, which probably serves only to confirm Simon's answer)

Comment: L'homonymie avec "héros" ne rend pas cette suggestion très viable pour un dialogue, à mon avis.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais "l'annonciateur de la mort".

That's the word that came most naturally to my mind, but if I had to analyze the motivations, I'd say

- it refers to a person, unlike a "signe avant-coureur"
- it's in a similar language register as "harbinger" (literary)
- it goes well with "mort" because it's often used with other dramatic predictions — eg "l'annonciateur de l'apocalypse"

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ added a bit of a rationale